# Because of alcohol consuming, cheeks are getting bigger. Is there a way to reduce it?

Tags: weight-gain, alcohol

Because of consuming alcohol my cheeks are getting bigger.

And i feel my weight is getting increased.

Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: Voted to close as being off topic for general health advice. But, you could always stop consuming alcohol.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think alcohol consumption directly causes cheeks to "get bigger".  You may have gained weight because while drinking alcohol people tend to consume extra calories.  Try consuming less alcohol and following a more sensible diet with exercise.

Comment: What kind of diet and exercise can i follow?

Comment: Without knowing more about you (age, medical condition, lifestyle), it's difficult to offer specific advice.  I would suggest you speak to either your family doctor, a registered nutritionist, or a registered personal trainer.

Comment: @DineshBabu Or just search this site, since diets and exercises for losing weight are already covered extensively. If you have any specific questions after reading through them you can always ask those.